# JMeter variables does not work with the request below

Tags: jmeter

How to get JMeter variables to work in this request?

```
"app_id": "$0${\\"app_id\\":\\"5908c437f2762d8b4b00037a\\",\\"eventID\\":\\"${my_variable}54fb80c0ce6fac8\\"}",
```

Comment: Please add more details to the question. Thanks!

Comment: @JWynn I do not see anything wrong in the syntax.

Comment: Is that comma at end intended?

Comment: That is part of the POST request body. The "View Results Tree" Request shows "$0${\"app_id\":\"5908c437f2762d8b4b00037a\",\"eventID\":\"${my_variable}54fb80c0ce6fac8\"}". Instead of picking up the "User Defined Variables", it shows "${my_variable}". My question is how do I get the variable work in this body?  Thanks!!!